# Выявление повторения последовательности

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дана бесконечно количество чисел, например  {5, 2, 7, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 1 ... }.Как видите числа 5, 2, 7, 8, 1 повторяются.

Как можно наиболее эффективно выявить эту последовательность?

Comment: У вас заранее известно, что вектор состоит из повторяющихся последовательностей, или, скажем, нужно найти две общие подпоследовательности максимальной длины?

Comment: Да, заранее известно что в вектор состоит из повторяющихся последовательностей.

Comment: И кроме этой последовательности ничего нет ? т.е. не могут попадаться элементы, не входящие в повторы ?

Comment: Для начала - рассмотреть длину вектора и решить, на какие подпоследовательности он может быть разделен. Например, в вашем случае 15 - означает либо 3, либо 5. Но `v[0] != v[3]` :)

Comment: Да, последовательность целиком и полностью состоит из одной  повторяющейся  подпоследовательности. Задача выявить что это за последовательность.

Comment: Harry, нету определенной длины вектора. Дан огромный вектор который может состоять как из 2 подпоследовательностей, так и из vector.size() / 2 подпоследовательностей,.

Comment: `vector.size()` есть? А далее работаем в зависимости от того, какая именно подпоследовательность вас интересует - самая короткая или самая длинная...

Comment: Harry, vector.size() нету и нельзя вычислить его. Суть в том, чтобы проверять вектор до тех пор, пока не выявим 2 одинаковые подпоследовательности.

Comment: Тогда последовательность не дана. Исправьте постановку задачи...

Comment: видимо нужен алгоритм с потоковым чтением последовательности, пока не достигнем конца последовательности. При этом  нужно в один проход чтения выявить последовательность.

Comment: http://mech.math.msu.su/~fpm/ps/k10/k106/k10609.pdf - вот, ищите тут, это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Harry, спасибо, сейчас просмотрю.

Comment: Или вот еще - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: А как звучала задача в первоисточнике?

Comment: Для бесконечной последовательности установить период невозможно же (если не известна формула, по которой вычисляется следующий член последовательности)

Comment: Либо должно быть условие, что внутри цикла числа не могут повторяться.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой алгоритм получился

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = {5, 2, 7, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 1}; //собственно наш вектор
    std::vector<int> repeating, repeating2; //служебные

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(std::find(repeating.begin(), repeating.end(), numbers[i]) != repeating.end()) //есть ли элемент в repeating
        {
            repeating2.push_back(numbers[i]);
            if (repeating == repeating2) //если массивы равны, выйти
            {
                break; 
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            repeating.push_back(numbers[i]);
        }


    }

    for (auto i : repeating)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> v;
//инициализируем некоторым количеством чисел
copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(v));    
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v));
//теперь в векторе две одинаковые последовательности
// решение:
int i = 2;
auto p = v.begin(), q = v.end();
while(vector<int>(p, p + i) != vector<int>(p + i, p + 2*i) && (p + i) != q)
    ++i;
//i -  это количество элементов двух одинаковых подпоследовательностей
// итак выводим последовательность, которая повторяется
copy(p, p + i, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```